# How to load CLR into process

Tags: .net, clr

I have some question which puzzled me for a long time.

1. What is the relationship between CLR
   and one process created by OS?
2. What steps the CLR is loaded when we double-click an "Console Application" or "Windows Forms Application"?
3. I found two methods: _CorExeMain() and _CorBindToRuntimeEx().  What's the role of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [Hosting the Common Language Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x0wh2z3.aspx), [Loading the Common Language Runtime into a Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01918c6x.aspx), [_CorExeMain Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh0859k0.aspx), [CorBindToRuntimeEx Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/99sz37yh.aspx).

I think the basic answer is, the CLR must run in a process (host).  If you "double-click", a process is created (initally purely unmanaged) then the CLR is loaded into the process (e.g. with CorBindToRuntimeEx).